# Installing Rasa on M1 Mac, resulting in -> source: no such file or directory: /Users/karan/miniforge3/bin/activate

Tags: macos, apple-m1, rasa

I'm trying to install Rasa on my M1 MacBook Air [following these instructions](https://forum.rasa.com/t/an-unofficial-guide-to-installing-rasa-on-an-m1-macbook/51342).

However, I am presented with this error:

```
Do you accept the license terms? [yes|no]
[no] >>>
Please answer
'yes'
or
'no':
>>
Please answer
'yes'
or
'no':
>>
Please answer
'yes'
or
'no':
>>> yes
Miniforge3 will now be installed into this location:
/Users/karan/miniforge3

  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify a different location below

[/Users/karan/miniforge3]>>>
ERROR: File or directory already exists: '/Users/karan/miniforge3'
If you want to update an existing installation, use the -u option
% source ~/miniforge3/bin/activate
source: no such file or directory: /Users/karan/miniforge3/bin/activate
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The install had an error:

> ERROR: File or directory already exists: '/Users/karan/miniforge3'
> you want to update an existing installation, use the -u option.If

So either try the -u or remove the install directory.

- Do `sh ~/Downloads/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh -u` instead.

**or**

- `rm -rf /Users/karan/miniforge3` if nothing is important in that directory. Then rerun the install.